# IP list adress separator in smb.conf

Tags: samba

How can I find the list separator in samba file.  I browsed the Internet but could not find a definitive explanation of what is the exact separator of the lists.

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf
[My_share]
(...)
host allow = 192.168.1. 192.168.2.
```

or

```
host allow = 192.168.1.,192.168.2.
```

or

```
host allow = 192.168.1., 192.168.2.
```

Is that or `,` or `,`<kbd>space</kbd> or something else.  How can I get the information?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the information?

From [the official samba documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch06.html) (my emphasis):

> Usually, **you can use whitespaces or commas to separate a series of
>   values in a list.** These two options are equivalent:
>
> ```
> netbios aliases = sales, accounting, payroll
> netbios aliases = sales accounting payroll
> ```